# Active X Pre-Loading

Tags: activex

I have an Active X that is approximately 1Mb big in file size and needs to be this size due to the task it needs to perform. When the user goes to the page where the Active X will be loaded from for the first time it takes the Active X just under a minute to load after clicking the button. If the user does not close their browser window and selects  the Active X again it will load in seconds.

Is there a way to pre-load Active X controls into the page so that it is ready when the user decides to use it by clicking a button?

Comment: Are you using HTTP compression to compress the 1mb file?

Comment: No - the Active X is created as a release MSI in Visual Studio